# Create ppsx from pdf

Tags: powerpoint, automator, beamer

for a presentation show, i have been asked to provide a powerpoint file. However i prefer LaTeX and beamer to create my slideshows. So i had the idea to create an automator script that extracts the images from my PDF file and create a PPT file.

I'm new at Automator but by googling i found pretty easily :

1. Ask for Finder Items.
2. Render PDF Pages as Images.( Resolution : 300)
3. Create Powerpoint Picture SlideShows

Unfortunately there is one problem : the pictures do not entirely fill the slides. After extraction from the pdf, the pictures are 1511*1133px (so 4:3) and my slideshows are 25.4*19.05cm (so 4:3) but it seems that powerpoint reduces the images because there are borders all around the pictures...

Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the images themselves, the version of PPT you have, your OS and its resolution settings, PPT uses various methods to determine the size of an imported image.  As long as the proportions match, manually resize them in PPT to fill the slide, or if you're automating the process, set each image's .Top and .Left to 0, set the .Width to ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth and .Height to ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight